# Class design: To hide "replaced" internal members or not to?

Tags: c#, .net, class-design

I am encapsulating access to a database in connection classes that all inherit from the same base implementation. This base implementation has a `protected` LINQ provider for database access that many child classes will use - but not all of them. Some might need their own provider and would then generally have no use for the "default" one.

This "other" provider would not be derived from the default one (but share a common quasi-abstract ancestor which in itself is of no use anywhere), but would have exactly the same role within the respective class, so it would seem nice to be able to use it in exactly the same way, i.e. use the same syntax. I could achieve this by hiding the respective members using the `new` keyword, but I'm unsure whether this is good practice.

On one hand, doing so would help avoiding accidentally using the wrong one because there is only one. On the other hand, being used to using the same name for the default and specific providers might lead to actually forgetting to implement a specific one and working with one that's not correct to use here. So it might make sense to name the default one appropriately; whoever will be developing a particular connection class will know when they need to use a specific provider and be reminded that they need to create the code to get to that.

Which reasoning is the more plausible one? I'm now leaning a bit towards the latter.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` keyword is *almost* always a bad idea.  It's one of those "last resort" features for cases where you have no other option, and in this case you definitely have other options.

Do the two providers have different semantics/APIs, or is the usage exactly the same?  If the latter, you might want to look into the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), and implement the property as a simple virtual property of type `ILinqProviderAdapter` (which you would define and implement), overriden where appropriate.